# Appium iOS 11 RemoteViewBridge - access default app sdk like Photo, Email

Tags: appium-ios

App has access to import image from photo and other option is sending doc via email. In automation I could access photo and email options once my app loads the ui on init. This was working in iOS 10 and Xcode 8. Now, Upon upgrade the Xcode to 9 and iOS 11 the same app is not allowing me to access the element in Photo and Email. When I checked the element in Inspector, it shows me the entire  Photo/Email page is RemoteViewBridge. Could you help me on this, how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerController class has a private view hierarchy. The collection view cannot be accessed anymore from appium. In ios 11 you cannot access these elements. Try using iOS 10.3 or wait for the fix. I am accessing using coordinates in my project for the time being.